# Calling App Files in my UIWebView website

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` app and I'm loading a website built with PHP, jQuery and Ajax. I have a few external jQuery plugin files that I call, along with some images.

EX: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>`

This makes the app load somewhat slowly... Is it possible to put the `jquery.easing.1.3.js` file into my "Supporting Files" folder within Xcode and then call the plugin on my website by doing something like:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="file://supporting_files/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>`

If so, what would be the extension to grab these files from my app?

**EDIT (ADDITIONAL CODE):**

In my `PHP` file:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
(along with other external files)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#body').fadeIn(500);
});
</script>

<body id="body>
```

So the page fades in when it is loaded... Obviously, this requires jQuery, and the app won't reveal the site when I try to inject jQuery...

In Xcode:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //load URL into webview
    [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                URLWithString:@"http://mydomain/file.php"]]];

}
```

Comment: This answer might be worth looking at ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279968/dynamically-loading-javascript-files-in-uiwebview-with-local-cache-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried JS Injection? You could use UIWebView's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method and load local JS files. There's a tutorial I googled for. Here it is:  http://www.ziconic.com/2010/10/javascript-injection-using-uiwebview.html

Comment: I was just looking at this, I found this tutorial: http://www.altinkonline.nl/tutorials/xcode/uiwebview/load-jquery-in-uiwebview/

Comment: I've discovered that this doesn't work for me... I need jQuery to load as the page is loading...

Comment: Both of the links are dead :(