# UIWebView show correctly remote page but not local in objective-c

Tags: html, objective-c, css, uiwebview

i'm creating an app in which i have a uiwebview.
I want to load a page saved in local using:

```
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

the problem is that css isn't correctly loaded so page will be shown incorrectly.

This page is still in remote ( i wanto to remove it from there ), so i try to load remote page:

```
NSString *strIndirizzo = @"foo.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strIndirizzo];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[web loadRequest:request];
[web setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

And it is correctly loaded. Where could be the problem? can you help me?

EDIT:
Solved CSS.. i don't know why css is loaded only outside the folder where it was. Now the problem concerns about jquery :/ i'm using jqtouch in remote page and it doesn't work in UiwebView local :/ anyone?

Comment: Can you add the tags that are being used to include the CSS and JS? Are you loading jquery from the remote server with a relative URL or from a CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the webview doesn't have the right path from which to handle the CSS link. Look at

```
– loadHTMLString:baseURL:
```

and

```
– loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:
```

on `UIWebView`. You'd want to give the `baseURL` as the place you saved the data.

Note this generally won't work if the CSS link uses an absolute path (starting with "/") or if you the HTML or CSS are not in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

JackTurky, in a fast search in google, i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720524/iphone-uiwebview-download-complete-page-with-css-and-images).

I Hope that this is going to help you.

Comment: Maybe help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792585/jquery-not-loading-on-the-iphone